# I m trying to post a question but this pop-up is given as an error

Tags: bug, status-completed

This message is given to me as the error:

Having some issues with floating-point numbers? Make sure you've read 
Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate? 
and 
Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary? 
They'll save you much frustration!

Comment: This might be related to this bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244607/your-tags-couldnt-be-submitted-please-see-the-error-above

Comment: It worked just now.